# How Apple knows if an app only runs on 6.1 or above?

Tags: ios

Just a small query :

When you develop the app, is it written somewhere in the code what iOS the app should run on?

We’re trying to determine how Apple knows if an app only runs on 6.1 or above.

Also – maybe you know for sure… if a user with 6.0 tries to download our app that requires 6.1 or above, what happens?  And, if a user with 6.0 already has the app installed (but not the update for 6.1 or above) are they still able to open the app?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A settings section is available in Xcode named as **Base SDK** . If this is 6.1, then app only runs on 6.1 or above. These informations are embedded with the binary you are uploading.

> if a user with 6.0 tries to download our app that requires 6.1 or
>   above, what happens?

If you select the app you want in the App Store and, if it's incompatible with your iOS version, a prompt will appear offering to let you download a previous, compatible version of the app.

Answer (score 0):

In respect to it being written in code, there is a preprocessor macro you can use to get the version you defined as the deployment target.

`__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED`

That'd return 60100 for 6.1 I believe. It seems that's not your question. Apple know because of the deployment target you set in the target general settings. If you set 6.1, then anyone below that can still run your app if they have it installed but cannot update or see newer versions.